# How to return a ENUM in string instead of integer

Tags: solidity

A `State` is defined and function to return state in smart contract:

```
enum State { ForSale, SellerDelisted, BuyerCancelled, BidPlaced, DepositMade, InDispute, Complete }
State public state;

function returnState() view external returns (State) {
    return state;
}
```

For a `state = State.Complete`, the state return is `6`. How can I get a string `Complete` returned instead?

Comment: How about `if (state == State.Complete) return "Complete";`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want neat code, then you could do something like this:

```
contract MyContract {
    enum State {
        ForSale,
        SellerDelisted,
        BuyerCancelled,
        BidPlaced,
        DepositMade,
        InDispute,
        Complete
    }

    State public state;
    mapping(State => string) public states;

    constructor() public {
        states[State.ForSale] = "ForSale";
        states[State.SellerDelisted] = "SellerDelisted";
        states[State.BuyerCancelled] = "BuyerCancelled";
        states[State.BidPlaced] = "BidPlaced";
        states[State.DepositMade] = "DepositMade";
        states[State.InDispute] = "InDispute";
        states[State.Complete] = "Complete";
    }

    function returnState() external view returns (string memory) {
        return states[state];
    }
}
```

However, function `returnState` performs 2 storage reads per call.

It is insignificant if you call this function using an externally-owned account, or even from a constant function in another contract.

But if you call it from a non-constant function in another contract, then these 2 storage reads cost 800 gas each.

Hence you're better off with non-neat code:

```
contract MyContract {
    enum State {
        ForSale,
        SellerDelisted,
        BuyerCancelled,
        BidPlaced,
        DepositMade,
        InDispute,
        Complete
    }

    State public state;

    function returnState() external view returns (string memory) {
        State temp = state;
        if (temp == State.ForSale) return "ForSale";
        if (temp == State.SellerDelisted) return "SellerDelisted";
        if (temp == State.BuyerCancelled) return "BuyerCancelled";
        if (temp == State.BidPlaced) return "BidPlaced";
        if (temp == State.DepositMade) return "DepositMade";
        if (temp == State.InDispute) return "InDispute";
        if (temp == State.Complete) return "Complete";
        return "";
    }
}
```

Here, function `returnState` performs only 1 storage read per call (`temp = state`), thus reducing the cost of calling it in a non-constant contract function, from 1600 gas to 800 gas.